# Как заполнить массив string числами?

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string first1[4];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        first1[i] = rand() % 15 + 1;
        cout << first1[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пытаюсь заполнить массив `first1` числами, но не получается, где я ошибся?

Comment: `rand() % 15 + 1` -> `std::to_string(rand() % 15 + 1)`

Comment: У вас числ*ами* заполняется не `string`, а *массив* `string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string first1[4];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        first1[i] = to_string(rand() % 15 + 1);
        cout << first1[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]